# ColorSense-For-XCode plugin not work in swift code

Tags: ios, plugins, swift, xcode6

I had use ColorSense-For-XCode plugin

[Plugin link](https://github.com/omz/ColorSense-for-Xcode)

and

[Demo video Link](http://maniacdev.com/2012/09/tool-uicolor-color-display-and-color-picking-extension-for-xcode)

I used in xcode 5.1 and also used in xcode6 beta in objective c code but in swift code it not work.
I search for that but not found.

I thought that in swift code there is changes in syntax so that's why this plugin not work.

So if anybody use this xcode plugin with swift code please share how to use it in swift code

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is fork that works with Swift: https://github.com/NorthernRealities/ColorSenseRainbow

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA It's a fork by other guy, because original project wasn't updated.

Comment: Oh.. Sorry i don't know. Thanks!

Comment: I think this fork is no longer maintained, either.

Comment: @Blaszard Updated link to another fork, which works.